# Rails 4 Bootstrap SASS - images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I am using Rails 4, with Bootstrap 3 (sass).

I have the following files in my project:

This css is in my framework_and_overrides.css.scss

```
.jumbotron {
margin-bottom: 0px;

background-image: image-url("jumbotron.jpg");
background-color: none;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

Note, i have seen posts which suggest that rails  doesn't recognise 'background-image' and should be replaced with 'background', and others that say that 'image-url' should be replaced with 'url'. Neither of these work for me.

The above css file is in the stylesheets tree, which gets included in my application.css.scss by:

```
*= require_self
*= require font-awesome
*= require_tree .
*/
```

My application view has this in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>testingthesetup</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "test" %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "t2" %>">
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>


<div class="jumbotron">

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting the view to render a jubmotron that has the background image in it. It doesn't give me anything. I amended the framework and overrides css to test that it was picking up the style by adding a background colour. That worked. There is a problem with the image that I can't find a solution to. I have tried using several images in jpg, gif and png formats. None of them work.

Does anyone have any advice as to why not? I have been fiddling with the way I have been defying the image path in the framework and overrides css all day. I'm now 6 hours in and have no hair left. Please help!

thank you.

Comment: load the bootstrap css before require tree option

Comment: Hi  Sabyasachi, thanks very much for the reply. The bootstrap instructions say not to do that - because it interferes with custom CSS. Have you had different experience?

Comment: Lets have a try .. by loading it ..